# Custom browser preferences for file download for PDF file

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use code which I found on Stackoverflow in other topics to do not ask user about action which should be taken to download PDF file.

Code which I'm using is:

```
 FirefoxProfile specialProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
 specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
 specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
 specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
 specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", Setup.DownloadContractPath);            
 specialProfile.SetPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
 specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);

 specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");

 return new FirefoxDriver(specialProfile);
```

But it seems that it's not working in my case. File I'm downloading is the type: PDF
And even if i'm using the code above i got the following screen:

[image]

Does anyone know what may i do wrong?

Comment: an alternative solution if you are working on windows is to use sendkeys and hit tab-tab and <enter> in order to click the OK button

Comment: Gah, why are you downloading something anyway?  Are you actually doing anything with it?

Comment: Hi, actually there was another process in the application which has been started on finish downloading the file. That's why i needed to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Firefox and Selenium version are you using?

I'm using Firefox 20.0, the default behaviour is to preview the pdf files rather than downloading, so I need to add `specialProfile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);`.

Apart from that your code works perfect for me. (Note I used Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() rather than your Setup.DownloadContractPath). Try it with [sample.pdf](http://static.mozilla.com/moco/en-US/pdf/mozilla_privacypolicy.pdf) and check if the preferences are actually in about:config page of your webdriver opened Firefox.

Here is a more detailed article: [Download PDF files automatically in Firefox using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/05/23/download-pdf-files-automatically-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver/)

```c#
FirefoxProfile specialProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); // my downloading dir
specialProfile.SetPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
specialProfile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");

specialProfile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true); // for my Firefox 20.0
return new FirefoxDriver(specialProfile);
```

Comment: Glad to know that. So do you know the reason why your code didn't work?

Comment: Hi, the missing part was: specialProfile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true); But i still dont know what this part is doing? And idea?

Comment: Firefox has buildin pdf parsing library to view pdf files and it takes control without those lines

Comment: It works, until you get   <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:application/pdf"
                   NC:alwaysAsk="true" /> added to your mimeTypes.rdf file inside profile root. So if it stops working - delete those lines (or better the whole file, since you can set this all up with browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk)

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing options now :

```
Dim fxOpt As New FirefoxOptions()

fxOpt.Profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
fxOpt.Profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fxOpt.Profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fxOpt.Profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); // my downloading dir
fxOpt.Profile.SetPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fxOpt.Profile.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
fxOpt.Profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
fxOpt.Profile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

WebDrv = New Firefox.FirefoxDriver(fxOpt)
```