# How to download file using remote Firefox webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, remotewebdriver

I've tried to adapt several existing solutions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251803/96588), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23800195/96588)) to the **remote** Firefox webdriver running in a [selenium/standalone-firefox Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-firefox/):

```
options = Options()
options.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/src/app/output')
options.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
options.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
options.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False)
options.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf')
options.set_preference('pdfjs.disabled', True)
options.set_preference('pdfjs.enabledCache.state', False)
options.set_preference('plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types', False)

cls.driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'firefox', 'acceptInsecureCerts': True},
    options=options
)
```

Navigating and clicking the relevant download button works fine, but the file never appears in the download directory. I've verified everything I can think of:

- The user in the Selenium container can create files in /src/app/output and those files are visible in the host OS.
- I can download the file successfully using my desktop browser.
- The response content type is `application/pdf`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that file is downloaded to the remote machine or container where the browser is running.

Comment: save yourself a ton of headaches and use an HTTP client to download files

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg The point is to test the frontend, so that's not an option.

Comment: As I remember, I had to add `'pdfjs.enabledCache.state', false` option to be able to download pdf in firefox, you can take screenshot after download to be sure firefox not open pdf instead of download. Also do you wait to file be downloaded, maybe browser closed before the file is downloaded.

Comment: in docker is not working, do you know how it comes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out other changes done while researching this were resulting in the server returning a text/plain document rather than a PDF file. For reference, this is the simplest set of options I could get to work:

```
options.set_preference('browser.download.dir', DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY)
options.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
options.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf')
options.set_preference('pdfjs.disabled', True)
```