# Download files automatically through firefox with nodeJS and webdriverio

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, automation, webdriver-io

I want to verify file download using NodeJS and Webdriverio. The file to download is of PDF format. When WebDriverIO clicks on "Download" Firefox opens up the following download confirmation window:[image: download confirmation pop-up]

I want Firefox to download the file automatically without showing above confirmation window, so I used the below code:

```
 conf_firefox.js file
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('deepmerge');
const baseConfig = require('./wdio.conf_base');

exports.config = merge(baseConfig.config, {
  services: ['selenium-standalone'],
  capabilities: [
    {
      maxInstances: 2,
      browserName: 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        prefs: {
          'browser.download.dir': path.join(__dirname, '../test-data/tmp/download/firefox'),
          'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'application/pdf',
        },
      },
      acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    },
  ],
});
```

but still Firefox shows the same window. How can I set Firefox profile so that PDF files are downloaded automatically without showing the confirmation dialogue?
For chrome everything works correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding following lines to perfs ->


'browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force' : false
'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting' : false

Comment: @NitinSahu unfortunately but it didn't help :(

Comment: It's strange that It's not working. I just came across this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800195/auto-download-pdf-in-firefox
You may try if this solves your problem

Comment: @NitinSahu found solution : just add 'pdfjs.disabled': true and instead of application/json used application/octet-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cap works for me:

```
{
  browserName: "firefox",
  "moz:firefoxOptions": {
    prefs: {
      "browser.download.dir": downloadDir,
      "browser.download.useDownloadDir": true,
      "browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force": false,
      "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": "application/pdf,image/jpeg,image/jpg,text/calendar,text/csv",
      "pdfjs.disabled": true,
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: Just added `'pdfjs.disabled': true` and instead of `application/json`, used `application/octet-stream`.

```
browserName: 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        prefs: {
          'browser.download.dir': path.join(__dirname, '../test-data/tmp/download/firefox'),
          'browser.download.folderList': 2,
          'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'application/octet-stream',
          'pdfjs.disabled': true,
        },
      },
```